# Remove padding from ComboBox

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm having trouble with removing the padding in the list of a `ComboBox`.

I filled the list with three buttons, and above the first button there is space and below the last button there is also space:

When closed

[image: When closed]

When opened

[image: When opended]

Another problem is that the list doesn't appear beneath the button, as you can see on the second picture.

This is the code (note there is no styling yet):

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="importComboBox" Margin="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ComboBox.PlaceholderText>Placeholder</ComboBox.PlaceholderText>
                <ComboBoxItem Padding="0" Margin="0">
                    <Button  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">button 1</Button>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Padding="0" Margin="0">
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">button 2</Button>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Padding="0" Margin="0">
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">button 3</Button>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

How can I remove those spaces and can I alter the dropdown position?

Comment: Are you sure you want to put buttons in a ComboBox? If you want to trigger an action when the user selects an item, you'd rather subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the ComboBox and save you all the trouble.

Comment: Agreed with @KooKiz that you probably don't want to do this. But if you want to change the template, right-click the XAML page, Open in Blend, then right-click and edit the template(s) for the control and its items.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure I want to use buttons, I don't want to have the user select something, I just want some kind of flyout menu with buttons that act the same as a combobox would "fly out", and I'm too lazy (for now) to write a custom control for it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter said, to achieve this we can modify the template of `ComboBox`. To modify the template of `ComboBox`, we can select the "**[importComboBox]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Template**"  → "**Edit a Copy...**".

To remove the padding in the list. Editor the `margin` property of `ItemsPresenter`. `ItemsPresenter` specifies where items are placed in a control.

```
<ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

To make the list appear beneath the button, we can editor  the `Margin` property  of `Border` in `Popup`. It determines the location of `Popup`.

```
<Border x:Name="PopupBorder" 
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" 
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="0,32,0,0">
```